# How to prevent context menu from showing in Chrome's device view

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I've got an `<input>` that onFocus is selecting the text:

```
onFocusHandler = (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.select()
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but when I view it in "Device" mode, each time the text is selected, the context menu shows up with "Look up <selected text>" at the top. Is there a different way to select the text that won't do this?

Comment: Did You tried to prevent contextmenu event?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко good suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Сергей Петрашко](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8086944/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE)'s comment, I gave this a shot:

```
<Input
  type="number"
  value={value || ''}
  onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
  onFocus={this.onFocusHandler}
  onContextMenu={e => e.preventDefault()}
  onUnfocusHandler={this.onUnfocusHandler}
/>
```

This prevents the context menu from showing. I also found that just using `onClick` to select the text does not show the context menu either (without preventing the `onContextMenu` event).

Comment: Good to know this, thanks, but I also want to warn future readers that if you handle `onClick` but _don't_ handle `onFocus` then you will not get the contents selected if you `tab` into the field. I tab a lot.